# Why does this code generate a b c and d slightly more than all other options?

Tags: php, security, random

This [lab](http://labs.eustasy.org/hash-check/generator-check) contains the code from this [repo](https://github.com/eustasy/hash-check) and nothing else. The following code is run to generate a million 1 character randoms from a set of lowercase letters and single digits.

```
<?php // Iterate the number of letters needed
for ( $Iterate = 0; $Iterate < $Length; $Iterate++ ) {
    $String .= $String_Characters[hexdec(bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(1))) % $String_Characters_Count];
}
```

As the chart in the lab shows, a, b, c, and d are far more likely to be generated than any other combination. They appear at the beginning of the string, not half-way through, so I assume that code is generating 1, 2, 3, and 4 more than others. Perhaps this is something todo with the `%` ?

**Update**
My solution has now been made from the answer below to use a slightly different tactic. It loses the option of setting acceptably characters myself but for salts that's not a huge deal. It is available here: http://labs.eustasy.org/hash-check/generator-check

Comment: Randomness and random distribution is ...very tricky. One would expect that the experts at http://crypto.stackexchange.com/ and http://math.stackexchange.com/ could tell you _a lot more_ about the characteristics a program _must have_ to have a reasonable chance for "producing" random distribuitons. A lot more than you can expect of stackoverflow.

Comment: I.. had no idea there was a crypto stackexchange. As for math, I'd be dubious about the understanding of programming there, although I admit there must be some.

Comment: Yes, the gap between practitioners (that would be us on stackoverflow) and theorists is a problem. I (as a practitioner) can only tell you what kind of "cookbook" I'd use - and that's: fetch as much "randomness" as possible in one step from a function that promises randomness and then do the translation without throwing away any data. You need 4bit nibbles? Fine, take a byte and translate it into 2 4bit elements instead of fetching two bytes throwing away 4 bits in each step. You need 5.5bits ...it's a bit harder, but don't throw away data from the rng.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't check it with php right now, but I can tell you the problem is in the %.

```
256 % 36 == 4
```

This means that the first 4 numbers will have a bit more chance of being outputted by the number generation. Specifically, it will be about 8/7 times more probable that the first 4 items in the array are selected than the others.

On the other hand, since you are using both strings and numbers as the array indexes, the actual order of the array may be different from what you output. My guess is, judging by the results, that you have first the a-z values and then the 0-9 values, so when you append the 0th, 1st, 2nd and 3rd items from $String_Characters, you are really appending "a", "b", "c" and "d" to the string.

Comment: Yeah..no. "A bit more uniform" doesn't cut it when you try to make something cryptographically secure, which seems to be the case here. So I'd just remove that part of your answer. The general solution is to simply use a divisor of 256 as the number of available characters: ...16, 32, 64, 128.

Comment: I know, my answer was more focused on why it happened. I listed a possible solution for it, but you are right, if its intent is to be cryptographically secure, it's not quite right. Going to edit it to make that clear.

Comment: I am still unclear on precisely where the 256 is coming from. Also, why is your proposed solution less secure? Surely the divisor is effectively performing the same operation already?

Comment: 256 is the number of values a byte can take, 2^8. So, dividing the random value by 256 you get a number in the range [0,1).

Comment: Actually, now that I think on it, my proposed solution probably has the very same flaw your naive approach had, only the 4 peaks will be spread between the 36 values instead of being together at the begining. That is the problem of trying to transform a granular finite set of numbers to what should be a complete range of numbers, as would be the entire [0,1) range. Therefore I deleted it.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not a statistician, but I'll try to answer. Pardon me for a possible wrong lexicon :)

You're right, it's something about the final `%`. If you remove it and plot the distribution, it's fine, end almost equally distributed. So the random algorithm is not to blame. Tha distribution *space* without the modulo is made by 256 slots. If you *shrink* that distribution to 36 slots (letters+numbers), you'll have to *map* some of those slots to a single one.

```
256 % 36 = 4
```

Given this simple hash function, 4 slots (the first four) will have *1 slot more* than the original distribution *slots*, which results in a higher element numbers as your charts show.

Instead, I'd expect an equally distributed chart if your `$String_Characters` is 32 characters long.

Comment: `$String_Characters` is variable in length, as there are options in the function to add Uppercase and Special characters into the mix. Otherwise, thank you for the answer.